# how to get post slug from url in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

i want to send post slug through URL and get on other page.
e.g, www.example.com/cars/mini-car
how can i get '**mini-car**' car type

i've found the way to get the id from url. that is;

```
$url = get_post_permalink(); //Get the url of the current post
 $substring_start_pos = strpos($url, 'pid=') + 4; //Find the position in $url string where the url number starts
 $url_number = substr($url, $substring_start_pos); //Extract the substring form the start position to the end of the url string
 $key_1_values = get_post_meta($url_number, '_song_name', true );
 echo "Your song is called $key_1_values";
```

i want to know how can i do with custom url (to get post slug of custom post type sent from previous page) like i mentioned as example

Comment: $post->post_name doesn't work? are you outside the loop or inside the loop? If outside you can use get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );

Comment: i am outside the loop. actually i want to display the list of that certain post type i am getting from url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **get_queried_object()** which holds the current queried object from where you can get the page slug which is held by the post_name property.

You can use as:

```
if ( is_page() )
    // // Get the page slug using queried object
    $my_slug = get_queried_object()->post_name;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

it is stored in the **post_name** field in database.
you can utilize the following code if you are inside a loop:

```
$the_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name' );
```

or if you are outside the loop:

```
$the_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_id);
```

where ***$post_id*** is the id of the post you want to retrieve from.

Comment: I don't think you need the get_post() - just `get_post_field( 'post_name' )` should do.

Comment: @Rup thanks, you are right, we don't actually need it if we are inside the loop, corrected..